# Disabled colors in buttons of UIAlertController

Tags: swift, swift3

I am trying to create a UIAlertController with 2 action buttons having default text color. Here is the code:

```
  let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)

                refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                    //dont bug user for permission for some time
                }))

                refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Notify me", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in

                    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .carPlay, .alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
                        print("Granted: \(granted), Error: \(error)")
                    }
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()


                }))
```

But I am getting the following output:

[image]

Why is the color of the action buttons light gray?

Comment: Is the `UIAppearance` protocol in effect somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a line similar to this somewhere in your code:

```
UIView.appearance().tintColor = .gray
```

Setting the tint color of the view appears to affect the color of the buttons. You'll need to remove that line or make adjustments as appropriate.

Maybe consider using `appearance(when​Contained​In​Instances​Of:​)` method.

```
UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIAlertController.self]).tintColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0/255.0, green: 122/255.0, blue: 255/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```